# boost/lockfree/queue.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost, queue

I am trying to play with  [boost::lockfree::queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html) but I dont know why the library is missing. I assume I have have installed the entire boost using `apt-get install  libboost-all-dev` 
am I missing something here?

From comments:

Does anyone know which debian package contains boost::lockfree::queue ? I double checked just now on a fresh installation: libboost-all-dev doesn't contain a lockfree subdirectory

thanks

Comment: Maybe setting the include paths?

Comment: Please provide source code

Comment: @RedX come on man! the /usr/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp file doesn't exist in my computer! nor does the corresponding libboost

Comment: @Araw how about the first example in the link?

Comment: @rahman if the file doesn't exist, you didn't correctly installed boost. try using `find` to locate the file if you're _sure_ that it must be installed

Comment: My answer provided as much information as it was possible with your "very exact" description of the error... You did not specifty the command line used to build so i assumed you are new and forgot that you need to set an include path. If you need precise instructions; give precise descriptions on your error report.

Comment: @stefan  that "is" my actual question: Does anyone know which debian package contains `boost::lockfree::queue` ? I double checked just now on a fresh installation: `libboost-all-dev` doesn't contain a lockfree subdirectory

Comment: @RedX ok bro, whatever. don't feel bad. kindly see the comments above. tq

Comment: Have you checked which version of boost is installed by the libbost-all-dev package? I think lockfree only exists from 1.53 onwards.

Comment: @RedX I see! no my version is 1.49 (This is the latest available by default)